# Java: Comparing an input to everything in a list without using a loop?

Tags: java, string, set

This is for a Hangman game.
I am using a SortedSet to store the guesses that the user inputs. These letters are stored as char. What I am trying to do is compare each character in a given word to every character in the SortedSet, and append a matched character to a returned String. If it doesn't match, a '-' is appended instead.

For example:

I have a set that contains the guesses: 'a', 'e', 't'

I have a word: apple

The method should return the string "a---e"

Right now, I have a method that generates a String that fits the format I need for one character. I am not sure how to modify it so it works for all characters in a collection.

I don't want to run the entire if/else structure for all of the characters in the collection as that would add too many dashes, so I don't think I can use a for-each loop.

```
private int generatePattern(String s, char guess) {
    String pattern = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (s.charAt(i) == guess){
            pattern += guess + " ";
        } else {
            pattern += "- ";
        }
    }
    return pattern;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well to start with it sounds like you should change your method's return type and parameters - you want a *set* of letters, after all. And *sets* have a `contains` method. So I think you want something like:

```
public static String hideNonGuesses(String input, Set<Character> guesses) {
    char[] result = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (!guesses.contains(result[i])) {
            result[i] = '-';
        }
    }
    return new String(result);
}
```

Or to put it a different way:

```
public static String hideNonGuesses(String input, Set<Character> guesses) {
    char[] result = new char[input.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        result[i] = guesses.contains(c) ? c : '-';
    }
    return new String(result);
}
```

(This could be done with Java 8 streams as well, but this is probably just as simple.)

Sample program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Set<Character> guesses = new HashSet<>();
        System.out.println(hideNonGuesses("apple", guesses));
        guesses.add('p');
        System.out.println(hideNonGuesses("apple", guesses));
        guesses.add('o'); // No change - it's not in the word
        System.out.println(hideNonGuesses("apple", guesses));
        guesses.add('a');
        System.out.println(hideNonGuesses("apple", guesses));
    }

    public static String hideNonGuesses(String input, Set<Character> guesses) {
        char[] result = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (!guesses.contains(result[i])) {
                result[i] = '-';
            }
        }
        return new String(result);
    }

}
```

Note that you're still looping over the input, and there may still be loops within `Set.contains` (depending on the implementation) but it gets the result you want...

Comment: Is there any reason why a Set would be better than an Array in this case, or was that personal preference?

Comment: @McAdam331: It's a better fit for what we want to test - which is whether or not each letter of the input is one of the guesses. We really want a contains operation, which is what a set is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your question?

In your code I think it is left one loop, may be guess should be the array of guessed letters and you could iterate over it inside your first loop. Instead you could call your generatePattern every time with every guessed letter.